# Find Match in 2 different rows - IF Else failing

Tags: vba, excel

Morning all,

I've found on multiple documentations the following code:

```
Sub Find_match()

    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim Range2 As Range

    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Select the range on the first sheet to
    Compare", Type:=8)

    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Select the range on the second sheet to
    Compare", Type:=8)

    Dim range_row1 As Integer
    Dim range_row2 As Integer
    Dim loop_row1 As Integer
    Dim loop_row2 As Integer
    Dim find_value As String

    range_row1 = Range1.Rows.Count
    range_row2 = Range2.Rows.Count

    For loop_row1 = 1 To range_row1
        find_value = Range1.Cells(loop_row1, 1)

        For loop_row2 = 1 To range_row2
            If Range2.Cells(loop_row2, 1) = find_value Then
                If Range1.Cells(loop_row1, 2) = Range2.Cells(loop_row2, 2) Then

                    Range1.Rows(loop_row1).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
                    Range2.Rows(loop_row2).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)

                End If
                ' Else
                '   Range1.Rows(loop_row1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

But when trying to put an else clause to allow the remaing cells to be "painted" in different colors, it actually superimposes the last color on a few of the previous values duplicated.

Comment: You're checking the values in Range1 to see if they occur in Range2 and shading if so? You could shade the whole range with the other colour at the beginning and then only shade those which match which will overwrite the original shading. Using Find or Match would be quicker than looping through every cell.

Comment: Done what you suggested and worked wonderfully. Cheers for everything, easy solution for a dumb question!